# Change detected on path app restarting on pm2

Tags: node.js, pm2

Everytime I write something in the logs I get this and the pm2 restart giving me an Service unavailable error in my webpage.

To write the logs I use

```
winston.info('some info');
```

and in the app.js I have this:

```
winston.add(winston.transports.File, { name: 'app-info', maxFiles: 3, filename: 'logs/app-info.log', level: 'info' });
```

How can avoid the pm2 to restart everytime I am writing in the log?

Comment: Please read [the fine manual](http://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/watch-and-restart/), in particular about the `ignore_watch` option.

Comment: I tried with `pm2 start app.js --ignore-watch="*.log"` and it didn't work still the same error

Comment: did you solve it ? i got some issue `Change detected on path combined.log for app API-NODEJS - restarting
PM2        | Stopping app:API-NODEJS id:1`

Answer (score 1):

i solved by ignore the log and watch

```
    watch: 'false',
    ignore_watch : [ "*.log"],
```

so full the code :

```
module.exports = {
  apps : [{
    name: "API-XXX",
    script: "/var/www/api/api-xxx-xxx/server.js",
    env: {
      NODE_ENV: "production",
    },
    env_production: {
      NODE_ENV: "production",
    },
    watch: 'false',
    ignore_watch : [ "*.log"],
  }],

  deploy : {
    production : {
      user : 'root',
      host : 'localhost',
      ref  : 'origin/master',
      repo : 'https://github.com/yogithesymbian/api-xxx-nodejs.git',
      path : '/var/www/api/api-xxx-nodejs/',
      'pre-deploy-local': '',
      'post-deploy' : 'npm install && pm2 reload ecosystem.config.js --env production',
      'pre-setup': ''
    }
  }
};
```

then run
 `pm2 restart ecosystem.config.js --env production`

i forgot the github disscussion to refer someone said put the line .

Answer (score 0):

You can resolve this problem using `--no-autorestart`,

example:

```
pm2 start app.js --no-autorestart
```